# Extra space in new column formed by combining two columns in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I would like to combine two column from database using SQL in Excel.

Concat(A,B) as C.

The problem is C have an extra space characters after the expected result

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just whitespace you can use `TRIM()` to remove any excess whitespace from the result

Comment: likely Trim(B) specifically, not Trim(C), If it is a formula =A1&Trim(B1)